# revert, or hard head and steps to follow

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've read a lot of posts and most lightly I'm going to get the duplication comment.

So remotely I have a bunch of commits on a branch called develop.
the last 3 are something like this.

```
f1....
f2....
f3....
f4....
```

I am working on another branch called feature/MT-100
Something happens on develop with the last 2 commits that messed up the build and I need to go back to the one of the old commits. For example f3....

Steps:

```
I stash everything i'm working on in feature/MT-100

checkout develop

git reset --hard f3....

git commit -a -m 'rolling back to f3.... fixed commit 

git push the new commit
```

My question if these are the correct steps is. Will I still have access to 
    f1....
    f2....
    f4.... 
remotely if I wanted to rollback to them later. or will f1 and f2 be wipped out by the --hard reset. Or does hard reset just effect my local history. Which in this case I'm ok because I don;t have any working files on local develop.

Would it be better to create a separate local branch called hotfix 
Stages:

```
git checkout -b 'hotfix'

git pull origin develop

git reset --hard f3....

git commit -a -m 'rolling back to f3... in a hotfix'

git push

raise a pr in stash

then merge from stash to develop
```

Am I gaining anything from the hotfix option to just doing --hard on local develop 
Is there a better way or more easier to understand way to do this. Again I won't have any working files on the hotfix branch so not worried about --hard.

Comment: Do you want f1 and f2 in your remote develop? If you don't, what I would do is just checkout the develop, hard reset to f3 and force push it to the remove develop branch. That way you just got rid of them and at least get the builds back. Of course it's always nice to just back up that broken develop branch first so that you can always cherry-pick the f1 and f2 back if needed. I personally never use revert, hard reset all the way!

Comment: Yes f1 and f2 are already in my remote and I want them to stay there in case I ever need to go back to them.